# обработка соприкосновений div-ов с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, css

не могу сделать обработку соприкосновений персонажа (div id="unit") и посторонних div . поможете ?
Пробовал с переработкой координат div-а , но заметил баг(теперь фича) : при обновлении страницы ,(в игре двигается не персонаж , а карта) позиция игрового поля(карты) сохраняется и становится 0  , по этому нельзя просто ввести

```
if(left_main <= -200 && left_main >= -250){ /*   ...   */ }
```

вот весь код

```js
 var left_main = 0;
            var bottom_main = 0;
            var speed = 100;
            var jump = 100;

            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

                let main = document.getElementById("main");

                if (event.code == "KeyD") {
                    left_main -= speed;
                    main.style.left = left_main + "px";
                }

                if(event.code == "KeyW"){
                    bottom_main -= jump;
                    main.style.bottom = bottom_main + "px";
                    if(left_main <= -400 && left_main >= -450 ){}else{
                        bottom_main += jump;
                        setTimeout(' main.style.bottom = bottom_main + "px" ', 200);
                    }
                }

                if(event.code == "KeyQ"){alert(left_main , bottom_main);}
               

                    if (event.code == "KeyA") {
                        left_main += speed;
                        main.style.left = left_main + "px";
                    }
            });
```

```css
 *{
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }

            #main{
                width:7000px;
                height:200%;
                background-color:#84bdff;
                position:absolute;  
                z-index:0;
                left:0;
                bottom:0;
                transition:ease left 0.1s;
                transition:ease bottom 0.1s;
            }
            #gnd{
                position:absolute;
                bottom:0px;
                width:100%;
                background-color:#229762;
                height:100px;
                z-index:1;
            }
            #stoneBox{
                width:50px;
                height:100px;
                background-color:#999;
                position:absolute;
                bottom:100px;
                left:700px;
            }

            #stoneBox:nth-child(1){left:1000px}
            #stoneBox:nth-child(2){left:1200px}
            #stoneBox:nth-child(3){left:1900px}
            #stoneBox:nth-child(4){left:2400px}
            #stoneBox:nth-child(5){left:2800px}
            #stoneBox:nth-child(6){left:3100px}
            #stoneBox:nth-child(7){left:3900px}
            #stoneBox:nth-child(8){left:4300px}
            #stoneBox:nth-child(9){left:4800px}
            #stoneBox:nth-child(10){left:5200px}
            #stoneBox:nth-child(11){left:5800px}

            #unit{
                width:30px;
                height:50px;
                background-color:#465bfa;
                border-radius:20px;
                position:fixed;
                bottom:100px;
                left:300px;
                z-index:100;
            }
            body{
                overflow:hidden;
            }
```

```html
    <div id="main">

            <div id="unit"></div>

            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>
            <div id="stoneBox"></div>

            <div id="gnd"></div>

        </div>
```

P.S. не критикуйте за отсутствие комментариев и если хотите можете поиграть чуть чуть (нормальной графики пока что нет , только обрубки)

Comment: `<div id="stoneBox"></div>` Необходимо заменить `ID` на класс, так как `ID` это уникальный Идентификатор и он должен быть один (одно уникальное имя)

Comment: мне кажется удобнее анализировать `el.getBoundingClientRect()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае, Вам необходимо полагаться не на положение элементов, а на координаты. 
Вам надо при нажатии на кнопку узнавать текущие координаты юнита и координаты блоков (Чтобы не прописывать каждый из них отдельно)
Так же для удобства поиска блоков - добавил им класс (Это будет правильней).
 И, как верно заменил Alexandr_TT, `id`- это идентификатор и нехорошо делать несколько блоков с одинаковым `id`, от этого нет практической пользы. (Лучше задайте им класс.)

Сделал Вам небольшой пример для наглядности, в котором при движении **Вправо** и пересечении блока - будет выводиться сообщение.
 (Другие стороны не стал брать - логика там точно такая же)
*** Важный момент: У Вас оформлено передвижение юнита таким образом, что он полностью может перескочить весь блок, (советую Вам его уменьшить) не стал его менять. 

Для понимания и корректного тестирования в данной конфигурации юнит должен находится на 4 шага левее первого блока (чтобы он его не перескакивал, а попадал на него) Но это уже детали размера шага. ***

Собственно вот пример:

```js
    var left_main = 0;
    var bottom_main = 0;
    var speed = 100;
    var jump = 100;

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

        function getCoords(elem) { // Функция получения координат нужного нам элемента (верх, право и лево)
            var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

            return {
                top: box.top + pageYOffset,
                left: box.left + pageXOffset,
                right: box.right + pageXOffset
            };
        }

        let main = document.getElementById("main");

        if (event.code == "KeyD") {
            left_main -= speed;
            main.style.left = left_main + "px";
            let first = document.getElementById('unit');
            let second = document.getElementsByClassName('stoneBox');
            for (i = 0; i < second.length; i++){
                let sr = getCoords(second[i]).right; //Получаем координаты правой стороны блока
                let sl = getCoords(second[i]).left; // Получаем координаты левой стороны блока
                let f = getCoords(first).right; // Получаем координаты правой стороны юнита
                let fl = getCoords(first).left; // Получаем координаты левой стороны юнита (При движении вправо на не нужны)
                if (f > sl && f < sr){ // Если правая сторона юнита находится между левой и правой стороны блока, то выводим сообщение "остановись" (Это для наглядности, в Вашем случае либо выполняем действие либо нет)
                    console.log('остановись!!!');
                } else {
                    console.log('можно двигаться');
                }
            }
        }

        if(event.code == "KeyW"){
            bottom_main -= jump;
            main.style.bottom = bottom_main + "px";
            if(left_main <= -400 && left_main >= -450 ){}else{
                bottom_main += jump;
                setTimeout(' main.style.bottom = bottom_main + "px" ', 200);
            }
        }

        if(event.code == "KeyQ"){alert(left_main , bottom_main);}


        if (event.code == "KeyA") {
            left_main += speed;
            main.style.left = left_main + "px";
        }
    });
```

```css
        *{
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }

        #main{
            width:7000px;
            height:200%;
            background-color:#84bdff;
            position:absolute;
            z-index:0;
            left:0;
            bottom:0;
            transition:ease left 0.1s;
            transition:ease bottom 0.1s;
        }
        #gnd{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0px;
            width:100%;
            background-color:#229762;
            height:100px;
            z-index:1;
        }
        #stoneBox{
            width:50px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:#999;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:100px;
            left:700px;
        }

        #stoneBox:nth-child(1){left:1000px}
        #stoneBox:nth-child(2){left:1200px}
        #stoneBox:nth-child(3){left:1900px}
        #stoneBox:nth-child(4){left:2400px}
        #stoneBox:nth-child(5){left:2800px}
        #stoneBox:nth-child(6){left:3100px}
        #stoneBox:nth-child(7){left:3900px}
        #stoneBox:nth-child(8){left:4300px}
        #stoneBox:nth-child(9){left:4800px}
        #stoneBox:nth-child(10){left:5200px}
        #stoneBox:nth-child(11){left:5800px}

        #unit{
            width:30px;
            height:50px;
            background-color:#465bfa;
            border-radius:20px;
            position:fixed;
            bottom:100px;
            left:300px;
            z-index:100;
        }
        body{
            overflow:hidden;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>     </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="unit"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="stoneBox" class="stoneBox"></div>
    <div id="gnd"></div>
</div>
```

Тут из-за съезда консоли видно не будет, прилагаю gif

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Про большую ширину шага : я её сделать для подсчёта расстояния , а так вообще она на 10 находится всегда . А про id вы правильно заметили , спасибо .